# Add character count function to foreach loop

Tags: javascript

I have created a character count function which calculates the length of characters use use and displays them at each key up. it works fine out of a loop but when I add it to the fore each loop for adding new rows it doesn't work.

Code below shows everything within the loop, the notes and description section is the classes which include the character count:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span18">
        <h2 class="PIMS3">Task Details</h2>
        <div id="taskList">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1">Dept</div>
                <div class="span1">Skill</div>
                <div class="span3">Description</div>
                <div class="span3">Notes</div>
                <div class="span6">Budget</div>
            </div>
             <div data-bind="foreach: tasks">


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span1"><select class="span1" data-bind="options: $parent.departmentList, value: department"></select></div>

                    <div class="span1"><select class="span1" data-bind="options: skillList, value: skill"></select></div>

                       <div class="span3"><input class="span3" name = "description" id="textAreaDescriptions"  data-bind="value: description"  placeholder="Max Character Limit 50" maxlength="50" >
                            <div id="char_namb2" style="padding: 4px; float: left; font-size: 12px; text-align: left;">Character Count:50:0</div>
                        </div>

                    <div class="span3"><input class="span3" name = "notes" id="textAreaNote"  data-bind="value: notes" placeholder="Max Character Limit 150" maxlength= "150">
                        <div id="char_namb3" style="padding: 4px; float: left; font-size: 12px; text-align: left;">Character Count:150:0</div>
                        </div>

                    <div class="span2" data-bind=" visible: skill() != 'RES' ">Hours: <input class="span1" placeholder="Hours" data-bind="value: budget_hours"</input></div>
                    <div class="span2" data-bind=" visible: skill() != 'RES' ">Cost Rate: <input class="span1" placeholder="Cost Rate" data-bind="value: budget_cost_rate"</input></div>
                    <div class="span2" data-bind=" visible: skill() != 'RES' ">Charge Rate: <input class="span1" placeholder="Charge Rate" data-bind="value: budget_charge_rate "</input></div>

                    <div class="span2" data-bind="visible: skill() == 'RES'">Other Cost: <input class="span1" placeholder="Other Cost" data-bind="value: budget_other_cost"</input></div>
                    <div class="span2" data-bind="visible: skill() == 'RES'">Other Charge: <input class="span1" placeholder="Other Charge" data-bind="value: budget_other_charge"</input></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                 </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2 offset1">
                    <a class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: addTask"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add Task</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2 offset1">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: save,visible: isValid() && !isSubmitting() "><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Create Job</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" data-bind="click: save,visible: isSubmitting"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Saving ... ...</a>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this snippet includes the script for character count function which is placed outside the loop.

```
<script>

$(function(){
    $('#textAreaDescriptions').keyup(function(){
        var charsno2 = new $(this).val().length;
        $('#char_namb2').html("Character Count:50 : " + charsno2);
    });
});
```

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#textAreaNote').keyup(function(){
        var charsno3 = $(this).val().length;
        $('#char_namb3').html("Character Count:150 : " + charsno3);
    });
});
```

Does anybody know how I could get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your php code?

Comment: sorry  @Hassan its within a phtml file

Answer (score 0):

In spite of the fact that you are using Javascript instead of PHP, try puting your functions inside a

```
$( document ).ready()
```

I think you are binding the event to the inputs before the DOM's load

****Edit****

I think that there are several issues with your code. Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/fmu9bj35/1/ where you have an example working.

Comment: Yes I realise that sorry put the wrong tag, thank you @Ivan Rodriguez Torres I will try this!

Comment: I am not sure if I have done this right but it still isn't working with functions inside the $( document ).ready(function()                           `<script>
            $( document ).ready(function(){
                            $(function(){
                                $('#textAreaDescriptions').keyup(function() {
                                    var charsno2 = new $(this).val().length;
                                    $('#char_namb2').html("Character Count:50 : " + charsno2);
                                });
                            }});
                        </script>`

Comment: Thanks I will check that link out!  @Ivan Rodriguez Torres

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work for a few weeks now.. it's very frustrating!! I have tried changing my code similar to the above suggested, but that doesn't work.. my functions count the characters fine. The problem is counting the characters of the task rows which are inside the loop "Tasks".. I cant seem to find anything relating to my problem only character counts, which is not my issues, my issue is the getting it to work in the loop... any further suggestions anyone has on the would be massively appreciated!!